# edit content of cell programmatically in bound datagridview

Tags: vb.net, data-binding, datagridview, edit

I would need to edit the content of a bound and filtered datagridview programmatically.

I tried following, but did not work:

```
DataGridView1.Rows(rcly).Cells(33).Value = "False"
```

I cannot edit de bound data table since the datagridview is filtered and I do not know at what location inside the dataset the value is that i have to edit, so I would like to edit it programmatically inside the datagridview and use the bindig to mirror the change in the data table in order to be able to use the filter funcion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataGridViewRow` has an `attribute` called `DataBoundItem`. You can access a `DataRowView` which has a `ReadOnly` attribute called `Row` which is the DataRow you want to edit.

I don't know if you can edit attributes of the `DataRow` since its ReadOnly. If you can't edit it then you will have to access the Row by using

```
 Dim TheRow as DataRow
 TheRow = DataGridView1.Rows(rcly).DataBoundItem.Row
```

To edit values in the `DataRow` use

```
TheRow.Item("ColumnName") = "Your new Value"
```

You can also access the Item by `Index`, but I would highly recommend using the name.

Comment: thanks, but i dont seem to be able to figure out how to actually edit the value.. your code does not have a "cell" item to edit..

Comment: Edited it into the answer

Comment: does not seem to work.. i get an error saying system.missingmemberexception (translated) impossible to find the public member 'rows' in type 'bindingsource'

Comment: Your DataSource is not a DataTable then. Try getting the DataTable using the BindingSource.

Comment: Sorry, it is a DataSet. my mistake.. dim Tabelle as DataSet

Comment: it works if you remove this line: `DataGridView1.DataSource.Rows(DataGridView1.DataSource.Rows.IndexOf(TheRow))` please remove it from your code so i can mark the answer as accepted

Comment: Done. Good luck! If you think about it, the line was pretty much a waste of code anyways :D